# Problema con POST de un formulario en Node.js

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express, ejs

Estoy haciendo conexión a un webservice con Node.js donde utilizo EJS para renderizar plantillas, tengo que hacer un formulario para extraer  un dato en el frontend y pasarlo  en el backend , pero el formulario que presento en el frontend se supone que tengo que poner la ruta en la ACTION="" y  poner METHOD="POST" y en otro archivo que ejecuto un `app.post("ruta",(req, res) =>{  res.send( recibido)`  cuando escribo en el formulario aparece Recibido, pero haciendo `console.log(req.body)` me aparece `undefined`, me podrían ayudar, se supone que si esta funcionando pero no envía nada, no se si mi codificación  no lo entiende , he checado  sobre el código de `app.use(express.urlcode({extend: false)})` algo así, lo intento y nada

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>
        
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="C:\Users\d_con\OneDrive\Desktop\Conexion\public\css\main.css">
        
        <%- include("partials/head") %>
    </head>
    <%- include("partials/navegation") %>
    <body>
        <div class="container vh-100 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
            <div class="card bg-dark text-light text-center p-4 rounded">
                <div class="card-header  ">
                    <h4>Consulta de Saldo</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body text-start ">
                    <form action="consulta" method="post">
                        <input type="text" name="title" autofocus>
                        <input type="url" name="URL">
                        <button>save</button>
                    </form>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>>
    <%- include("partials/footer") %>
</body>
</html>
```

Código del POST

```
const expres = require("express");
const router = expres.Router();

const llamarapi = require("../consumirapi");

router.get("/consulta", (req, res) => {
  res.render("consulta");
});
router.post("/consulta", (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);

  res.send("Recibido");
});

module.exports = router;
```

Código del index

```
const exp = require("constants");
const express = require("express");
const morgan = require("morgan");
const app = express();
const port = 3000;
const path = require("path");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.set("views");
app.set("public", path.join(__dirname, "public"));

app.use(require("./routes/links"));
app.post("/index.js", (req, res) => {
  const id = req.body.id;
  // Hacer algo con la ID recibida
  console.log(id);

  // Enviar una respuesta al frontend
  res.json({ mensaje: "ID recibida correctamente" });
});

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.render("index");
});
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.json());

app.get("/saldo", (req, res) => {
  res.render("saldo");
});
    
app.use(express.static("public"))
app.listen(port)
```

Comment: En el código tienes varias cosas que no usas, cierras dos veces la etiqueta form.

Comment: La parte donde recibes el POST, es `routes/links` ? Asegúrate de usar el middleware `bodyParser` antes de declarar esas rutas